# Python script to insert LCSs and additional models in FreeCad Assembly 4

Tags: python-3.x, freecad

For each model I want to insert multiple LCSs at fixed points. I have enough to insert the LCS itself and set an offset. But the LCS also needs a point to reference. Does anybody know the script to add the reference point (in the GUI it's listed under coordinate system parameters)? Additionally, does anybody know the script to insert additional models into an assembly?

```
App.getDocument('Model_1').Model.newObject('PartDesign::CoordinateSystem','LCS_1')
App.getDocument('Model_1').getObject('LCS_1').AttachmentOffset = App.Placement(App.Vector(-185.8, 0, 2.375),  App.Rotation(0, 0, 0))
```